# ¿Cómo contar la ocurrencia de observaciones en data frame en R?

Tags: r, rstudio, dataframe

Estoy dándole vueltas y no logro poder resolver esto:
Tengo el siguiente data frame

```
D1  D2  D3  D4 Prot

1   NA  NA  NA  6
2   10  NA  NA  1
2   NA  NA  NA  1
3   1   NA  NA  1
3   24  NA  NA  1
3   25  NA  NA  1
5   NA  NA  NA  34
8   9   1   NA  1
```

Donde D1, D2, D3, D4 son demandas (en una protesta) y Prot corresponde a cantidad de protestas con esas demandas. Necesito saber la cantidad total de protestas con cada demanda, es decir contar la cantidad de ocurrencias de la demanda (1) en las columnas D1,D2,D3,D4 multiplicada por la cantidad de protestas (Prot).

Answer (score 0):

Te refieres a esto?

```
  D1 D2 D3 D4 prot D_1 D_2 D_3 D_4
1  1 NA NA NA    6   6  NA  NA  NA
2  2 10 NA NA    1   2  10  NA  NA
3  2 NA NA NA    1   2  NA  NA  NA
4  3  1 NA NA    1   3   1  NA  NA
5  3 24 NA NA    1   3  24  NA  NA
6  3 25 NA NA    1   3  25  NA  NA
7  5 NA NA NA   34 170  NA  NA  NA
8  8  9  1 NA    1   8   9   1  NA
```

```
> sumD_1
[1] 197
> sumD_2
[1] 69
> sumD_3
[1] 1
> sumD_4
[1] 0
```

Si es así aquí el código:

```
df[,1:5]<-apply(df[,1:5], 2, as.character)
df[,1:5]<-apply(df[,1:5], 2, as.numeric)

for (i in 1:4) {
  df[,paste0("D_",i)]<-df[,paste0("D",i)]*df$prot
  assign(paste0("sumD_",i), sum(df[,paste0("D_",i)], na.rm = T))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenida Victoria.

Entiendo que quieres multiplicar cada valor de demanda por la columna `Prot` y que el resultado final sería una matriz o data.frame de 8 filas por 4 columnas. Si no es así por favor agrega un comentario a esta respuesta o una aclaración a tu pregunta.

En ese caso podrías solucionarlo con R base usando la función `apply()`.

```
#Genero los datos
structure(list(D1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 8), 
               D2 = c(NA, 10,NA, 1, 24, 25, NA, 9), 
               D3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1), 
               D4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
               Prot = c(6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 34, 1)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -8L), 
          class = c("data.frame")) -> datos_protestas


apply(datos_protestas[, 1:4], 2, function (x) x * datos_protestas$Prot)
```

## Explicación

`apply()` se encarga de pasar una (otra) función a cada fila o columna de un data.frame. El primer argumento es el data.frame sobre el que va a trabajar, en este caso uso un subset para que trabaje solamente sobre las columnas con números de índice 1 a 4. La idea es que no multiplique a `Prot` por sí misma, así que excluyo la columna 5.

El número 2 como segundo argumento le indica a `apply()` que quiero que opere por columnas. Usando el 1 haría las operaciones por filas.

`function (x)` define una función anónima. Es un truco para no tener que definir una función previamente. `apply()` se va a encargarde ir suministrando a mi función cada columna en el argumento `x`. Luego defino la función, que es la multiplicación de `x` (cada columna) por el vector `datos_protestas$Prot`.

`apply()` se encarga solita de armar la matriz de salida.

Así se ve el resultado:

```
      D1 D2 D3 D4
[1,]   6 NA NA NA
[2,]   2 10 NA NA
[3,]   2 NA NA NA
[4,]   3  1 NA NA
[5,]   3 24 NA NA
[6,]   3 25 NA NA
[7,] 170 NA NA NA
[8,]   8  9  1 NA
```

Cuando hay un `NA` (missing) el resultado de las operaciones aritméticas siempre será `NA`.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, creo que me expresé mal, porque las demandas no se multiplican por las protestas, ya que cada numero corresponde a una demanda. Es decir las D_ son de distintos demandantes en la misma protesta. Por eso, yo lo que estoy buscando es contar la cantidad de veces que aparece cada demanda en la tabla independientemente de si pertenece a D_1, D_2, D_3 o D_4

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la solución más adecuada, es la que te dio mpaladino, sin embargo, en algún escenario puede ser de utilidad pensar el problema de una forma diferente: como una simple multiplicación de matrices.

```
demandas <- c("D1","D2","D3","D4")
prot <- matrix(rep(datos_protestas$Prot,length(demandas)), ncol=length(demandas))
prot

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    6    6    6
[2,]    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1
[5,]    1    1    1    1
[6,]    1    1    1    1
[7,]   34   34   34   34
[8,]    1    1    1    1
```

Como se puede observar hemos definido una matriz que repite cada columna con el valor de `prot` tantas veces como demandas tengamos, luego hacemos un simple producto entre ambas matrices:

```
datos_protestas[, demandas] * prot

   D1 D2 D3 D4
1   6 NA NA NA
2   2 10 NA NA
3   2 NA NA NA
4   3  1 NA NA
5   3 24 NA NA
6   3 25 NA NA
7 170 NA NA NA
8   8  9  1 NA
```